# Reshaping numpy array and converting columns to rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am sorry for the vagueness of the heading. I have the following task that I can't seem to solve. I have an array of shape `(4,2,k)`. I want to reshape it to shape `(2,k*4)` while converting columns to rows.

Here is a sample input array where k=5:

```
sample_array = array([[[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
                       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

                      [[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
                       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

                      [[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
                       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

                      [[2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
                       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

I have managed to get desired output with a `for-loop`

```
twos=np.array([])
ones=np.array([])

for i in range(len(sample_array)):
    twos = np.concatenate([twos, sample_array[i][0]])
    ones = np.concatenate([ones, sample_array[i][1]])

desired_array = np.array([twos, ones])
```

where `desired array` looks like this:

```
array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Is there a more elegant solution to my task? I have tried .reshape(), .transpose(), .ravel() but never seem to get the desired outcome.

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, I have looked through a few dozen StackOverflow Qs but found no solution.

Comment: look at the `np.transpose` docs

Comment: @hpaulj thank you. I did, but didn't manage to get desired result.

Comment: `transpose` can do the same thing as `swapaxes`

Comment: The `hstack` treats the array as 4 arrays of shape (2,5), and concatenates them on the last dimension.  The `swapaxes/transpose` approach makes a (2,4,5) array, and reshapes that to (2,20).  Your attempt made 2 arrays of length 20, and joined them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simple horizontal stack `hstack` should work fine:

```py
>>> np.hstack(sample_array)

array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `swapaxes` and `reshape`:

```
sample_array.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(sample_array.shape[1], -1)
```

output:

```
array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```